# Can you accidentally cause significant downtime by making a typo in a CNAME or A rec?

Tags: url, networking, dns, cname

Let's say I need to change the CNAME for my subdomain test.mysite.com.
I want it to go to a load balancer endpoint 'aws-my-endpoint.com'.

But in creating the CNAME, I type it wrong. e.g. 'aw-my-endpoint.com'

Since it's possible that a client can cache DNS for up to 48hrs (despite what the TTL setting is), could this cause test.mysite.com to be down for 48hours? Even though I immediately fix the CNAME after noticing the typo?

Comment: In theory yes it could take upto 78 hours. But in practice, I have never observed DNS propogation takes that longer. You can check the dns progration in websites like https://dnschecker.org/

Answer (score 0):

Yes. I've seen with ELB to ALB transitions where clients still hit the ELB, sometimes for days. Most traffic however, usually take a few minutes to port over.

But with a non-existent target (like a typo in your case), there's a chance it would be faster since clients typically wouldn't cache a failed response. The resolvers may cache but they'd respect the TTL specified on the record. There's more on this behavior on this [thread](https://serverfault.com/questions/426807/how-long-does-negative-dns-caching-typically-last)

Comment: ah that is good news "clients typically wouldn't cache a failed response"